# Button only posts back the first time it's pressed after page load

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am creating a DotNetNuke module which is a simple text field which the value is then passed to stored procedure and results bound to grid.

When I first load the page, I can enter a term - hit 'search' button and I can see in debug that the buttons click is processed - and results are returned.

However the next time I press the button there is no postback? Even my breakpoint on Page_Load doesn't hit?

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes! I set the DefaultCacheTime to 0 and now it's working fine!

Comment: Yeah, you generally don't want caching in a module that's interactive in any way.

Answer (score 2):

DNN is working to improve this. There are some hopeful plans underway to change the way dynamic modules are cache.  For the time being, you do not want to cache modules that have dynamic content.